# How to put dates from a for next loop in cells of excel

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm currently trying to do a simple for next loop in excel. I'm working with dates, so I declare a start date and the end date. I just need to display the dates contained among those two dates in different cells.

I got this using only integer numbers but with dates I don't get it yet.

I did a test with a MsgBox and It works (pressing enter key) until reach the last date (end date) but I can't get put it in a range of cells, probably the solution is to simple but I spent to much time in this... 
Please help me

This in my code

```
Sub looping()

Dim fecha_ini As Date
Dim fecha_fin As Date
Dim conteo As Date
Dim rango_inicio As Range


fecha_ini = #1/1/2015#
fecha_fin = #1/15/2015#

Set rango_inicio = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")

For conteo = fecha_ini To fecha_fin

    Range("A" & 1).Value = conteo

Next conteo
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
Sub looping()

Dim fecha_ini As Date, fecha_fin As Date, conteo As Variant, rango_inicio As Range, i As Integer

fecha_ini = #1/1/2015#
fecha_fin = #1/15/2015#
i = 1
Set rango_inicio = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")
For conteo = fecha_ini To fecha_fin
    Cells(i, 1).Value = conteo
    i = i + 1
Next conteo

End Sub
```

I added a counter "i", and had the For loop assign values to cells using Cells(row, column) instead of Range(...).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..

Instead of setting the Range to A1, just set the values using a .Cells loop with a variable instead of the number you were currently using.
ie, .Cells(row, col) instead of .Range("A" & 1)

```
sub Looping()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim fecha_str As String
Dim fecha_date As Date

    For lRow = 1 to 15 

        fecha_str = "1/" & lRow & "/2015"
        fecha_date = CDate(fecha_str)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "A").Value = fecha_date

    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: This should provide some ideas of looping and building strings, and it would work, but the solution provided by @Jeeped is more true to form for the purpose.  I'm leaving this answer because it might provide useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
'=============================================================
'using for each

    Sub looping()
        Dim fecha_ini As Date, fecha_fin As Date, conteo As Date
        Dim rango_inicio As Range, D As Long
        fecha_ini = #1/1/2015#
        D = DateDiff("d", #1/1/2015#, #1/15/2015#) + 1
        For Each rango_inicio In Range("A1:A" & D)
            rango_inicio.Value = fecha_ini
            fecha_ini = fecha_ini + 1
        Next
    End Sub
'=============================================================
'using while wend or do while loop 

   Sub looping2()
        Dim fecha_ini As Date, fecha_fin As Date, conteo As Date
        Dim D&, i&
        fecha_ini = #1/1/2015#
        D = DateDiff("d", #1/1/2015#, #1/15/2015#) + 2
        i = 1
        While i <> D
            Cells(i, 1).Value = fecha_ini
            fecha_ini = fecha_ini + 1
            i = i + 1
        Wend
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are intended to be sequential, a `.DataSeries` would be more efficient than a loop.

```
Sub no_looping()
    Dim fecha_ini As Date, fecha_fin As Date

    fecha_ini = #1/1/2015#
    fecha_fin = #1/15/2015#

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
        .Cells(1, 1) = fecha_ini
        .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, _
          Date:=xlDay, Step:=1, Stop:=fecha_fin, Trend:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

The `.Cells(1, 1)` refers to the first cell in whatever range you are working on. This needs to be *seeded* with the first value to start the series on. If you were working on Z99:Z999 then `.Cells(1, 1)` would refer to Z99.

Comment: I prefer this over my solution.  This is a lot better than building a string, by concatenating it with a variable and converting it to a date.  It's also more true to the OP form, looks like what he was intending.